# How to send HTTP request in Java?

Tags: java, html, http, httpwebrequest

In Java, How to compose an HTTP request message and send it to an HTTP web server?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html In particular, getHeaderField, getHeaderFieldKey, and getContent

Comment: [There's a mini tutorial here at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).

Comment: You could use the JSoup lib (http://jsoup.org) . It does exactly what you ask!
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org"). get();
(from the site).
A more pythonic way for java.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

You can use [java.net.HttpUrlConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Example ([from here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139)), with improvements. Included in case of link rot:

```
public static String executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;

  try {
    //Create connection
    URL url = new URL(targetURL);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
        Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    //Send request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
        connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.close();

    //Get Response  
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if Java version 5+
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(line);
      response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    return response.toString();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  } finally {
    if (connection != null) {
      connection.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is another nice code snippet in replace for Java Almanac: [HttpUrlConnection-Example](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139)

Comment: Putting some actual code into this answer will help avoid link rot...

Comment: Since Java 9, creating HTTP request [has become much easier](https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request).

Comment: Yes, a lot has changed in the ten years since this answer was given.  Not everyone has moved on from JDK8 to 9 and beyond.

Comment: How to put some header content in the request with this way of doing, please ?

Answer (score 248):

From [Oracle's java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The strange thing is that some servers will reply you back with strange ? characters (which seems like an encoding error related to request headers but not) if you don't open an output stream and flush it first. I have no idea why this happens but will be great if someone can explain why?

Comment: @Gorky: Make a new question

Comment: This is way too much line noise to send an HTTP request imo. Contrast to Python's requests library: `response = requests.get('http://www.yahoo.com/')`; something of similar brevity should be possible in Java.

Comment: @leo-the-manic that's because Java is supposed to be a lower level language (than python) and allows (forces) the programmer to handle the details underneath rather than assuming "sane" defaults (i.e. buffering, character encoding, etc.). It is possible to get something as succinct, but then you lose lots of the flexibility of the more barebones approach.

Comment: @leo-the-manic If there is no such thing as you look for, do go and write by yourself. I do that all the time and I do have quick get/post static methods on both java and C#

Comment: @fortran Python has equally low-level options to accomplish the same thing as above.

Comment: That's exactly why Java is stopped being thought in schools. Relic of the history.

Comment: @fortran Java is not 'lower level' than Python... how does that make any sense?

Comment: What  Dan Passaro is saying is there should be a wrapper for all that code.  And the wrapper should be part of the Plain Old Java Objects.  So he (and me) don't need to worry about all of the under-the-hood mechanics.  That would be a class that has, as input, the URL, and as output, the String [] array. or just one long string.

Comment: my wrapper:
// import java.net.*;
// import java.io.*; 
 public static String getWebPage(String targetURL) {
  String s = "", t = "";
  URL url = null;
  URLConnection connection = null;
  try {
   url = new URL(targetURL);
   connection = url.openConnection();
   connection.connect();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     connection.getInputStream()));
   while ((t = in.readLine()) != null) {
    s = s + "\n" + t;
   }
   in.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return s;
 }

Comment: One of the few answers that really comes in full with `import` instead of thinking implying there'll be an IDE that figures this out for you.

Answer (score 74):

I know others will recommend Apache's http-client, but it adds complexity (i.e., more things that can go wrong) that is rarely warranted. For a simple task, `java.net.URL` will do.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.y.com/url");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
try {
  /* Now read the retrieved document from the stream. */
  ...
} finally {
  is.close();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help if you want to monkey with request headers, something that's particularly useful when dealing with sites that will only respond a certain way to popular browsers.

Comment: You can monkey with request headers using URLConnection, but the poster doesn't ask for that; judging from the question, a simple answer is important.

Answer (score 57):

[Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/). The examples for the two modules - [HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html) and [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) will get you started right away.

Not that HttpUrlConnection is a bad choice, HttpComponents will abstract a lot of the tedious coding away. I would recommend this, if you really want to support a lot of HTTP servers/clients with minimum code. By the way, HttpCore could be used for applications (clients or servers) with minimum functionality, whereas HttpClient is to be used for clients that require support for multiple authentication schemes, cookie support etc.

Comment: FWIW, our code started with java.net.HttpURLConnection, but when we had to add SSL and work around some of the weird use cases in our screwy internal networks, it became a real headache. Apache HttpComponents saved the day.

Our project currently still uses an ugly hybrid, with a few dodgy adapters to convert java.net.URLs to the URIs HttpComponents uses. I refactor those out regularly. The only time HttpComponents code turned out significantly more complicated was for parsing dates from a header. But the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1930240/1450294) for that is still simple.

Comment: It would be helpful to add a code snippet here

Answer (score 30):

Here's a complete Java 7 program:

```
class GETHTTPResource {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL("http://example.com/").openStream())) {
      System.out.println(s.useDelimiter("\\A").next());
    }
  }
}
```

The new try-with-resources will auto-close the Scanner, which will auto-close the InputStream.

Comment: @Ska There is no unhandled exception. `main()` throws Exception, which encompasses the MalformedURLException and the IOException.

Comment: Scanner actually is not very optimized when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 16):

Google [java http client](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) has nice API for http requests. You can easily add JSON support etc. Although for simple request it might be overkill.

```
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Network {

    static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    public void getRequest(String reqUrl) throws IOException {
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(reqUrl);
        HttpRequest request = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(url);
        HttpResponse response = request.execute();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());

        InputStream is = response.getContent();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) ch);
        }
        response.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'transport'?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `HTTP_TRANSPORT`, I've edited the answer.

Comment: why is HttpResponse not AutoClosable? What is the difference from this and to working with Apache's CloseableHttpClient?

Comment: The benefit is the API, which makes it personal preference really. Google's library uses Apache's library internally. That said, I like Google's lib.

Comment: Simple or complex requests doesn't matter, readability is the king.

Answer (score 15):

This will help you. Don't forget to add the JAR `HttpClient.jar` to the classpath.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

public class MainSendRequest {

     static String url =
         "http://localhost:8080/HttpRequestSample/RequestSend.jsp";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Instantiate an HttpClient
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        //Instantiate a GET HTTP method
        PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
        method.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

        //Define name-value pairs to set into the QueryString
        NameValuePair nvp1= new NameValuePair("firstName","fname");
        NameValuePair nvp2= new NameValuePair("lastName","lname");
        NameValuePair nvp3= new NameValuePair("email","email@email.com");

        method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[]{nvp1,nvp2,nvp3});

        try{
            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

            System.out.println("Status Code = "+statusCode);
            System.out.println("QueryString>>> "+method.getQueryString());
            System.out.println("Status Text>>>"
                  +HttpStatus.getStatusText(statusCode));

            //Get data as a String
            System.out.println(method.getResponseBodyAsString());

            //OR as a byte array
            byte [] res  = method.getResponseBody();

            //write to file
            FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("donepage.html");
            fos.write(res);

            //release connection
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously, I really like Java, but what's the matter with that stupid `NameValuePair` list or array. Why not a simple `Map<String, String>`? So much boilerplate code for such simple use cases...

Comment: @Joffrey Maps by definition have 1 key per value, means: `A map cannot contain duplicate keys` ! But HTTP Parameters can have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 14):

You may use Socket for this like

```
String host = "www.yourhost.com";
Socket socket = new Socket(host, 80);
String request = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(request.getBytes());
os.flush();

InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
int ch;
while( (ch=is.read())!= -1)
    System.out.print((char)ch);
socket.close();
```

Comment: @laksys why it should be `\r\n` instead of `\n`?

Comment: @CuriousGuy look at this link http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n

Comment: It seems to be even easier and more straight forward than the other solutions. Java makes things more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Java **11** or newer ([except on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65363995/8583692)), instead of the legacy *HttpUrlConnection* class, you can use Java 11 new [HTTP Client API](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html).

##### An example *GET* request:

```java
var uri = URI.create("https://httpbin.org/get?age=26&isHappy=true");
var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
var request = HttpRequest
        .newBuilder()
        .uri(uri)
        .header("accept", "application/json")
        .GET()
        .build();
var response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
System.out.println(response.statusCode());
System.out.println(response.body());
```

The same request executed asynchronously:

```java
var responseAsync = client
        .sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);
// responseAsync.join(); // Wait for completion
```

##### An example *POST* request:

```java
var request = HttpRequest
        .newBuilder()
        .uri(uri)
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer fake")
        .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString("{ title: 'This is cool' }"))
        .build();
var response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

For sending form data as multipart (`multipart/form-data`) or url-encoded (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) format, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56482187/8583692).

See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client) for examples and more information about HTTP Client API.

##### For Java standard library HTTP **server**, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71635295/8583692).

Answer (score 7):

There's a great link about sending a POST request [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120101100355/http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html) by Example Depot::

```
try {
    // Construct data
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/cgi");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process line...
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

If you want to send a GET request you can modify the code slightly to suit your needs. Specifically you have to add the parameters inside the constructor of the URL. Then, also comment out this `wr.write(data);`

One thing that's not written and you should beware of, is the timeouts. Especially if you want to use it in WebServices you have to set timeouts, otherwise the above code will wait indefinitely or for a very long time at least and it's something presumably you don't want.

Timeouts are set like this `conn.setReadTimeout(2000);` the input parameter is in milliseconds