# How to parse Date from HTTP Last-Modified header?

Tags: java, http, date, http-headers

HTTP Last-Modified header contains date in following format (example):
`Wed, 09 Apr 2008 23:55:38 GMT`
What is the easiest way to parse **java.util.Date** from this string?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This should be pretty close

```
String dateString = "Wed, 09 Apr 2008 23:55:38 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date d = format.parse(dateString);
```

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: +1 almost correct, the `hh` should be `HH`, as the hours are 0-23.

Comment: I also had the timezone "ZZZ" instead of "zzz".  Hopefully that will do it.  If you still have issues you can reference the documentation linked above.

Comment: Works great for me, thank you! The only thing that I should say is that this example is for Locale.ENGLISH.

Comment: If you're doing this often make sure you reuse the SimpleDateFormat object (they're amazingly expensive to construct) and synchronize on it  when calling `parse` (they're not threadsafe).

Comment: The standard allows not one format, but **three** formats. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3

Comment: If you are going to compare that Date object to a time stamp in your application, remember that the header **only include whole seconds** and  you should discard the 3 least significant digits to be able to compare properly. So do (TS/1000)*1000 == headerTS if needed.

Comment: Anyone getting a "ParseException: Unparseable date"?

Comment: @Ry4an synchronizing is an option as DateFormat instances are not threadsafe, but using a ThreadLocal variable can be more efficient if the instance is going to be contended for often.

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 09 Apr 2008 23:55:38 GMT"at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: I think it could be `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US);` not to fail on other locales.

Comment: To avoid `ParseException` use `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US)` instead

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified states that the time zone must always be exactly "GMT". Therefore, a `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` is is necessary, when using the same format for also creating `Last-Modified` header values.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar Two of the three formats are now obsolete, so `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US)` is all you need now.  [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#page-65](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#page-65)

Comment: Submitted an edit request according to @DylanSmith 's comment.

Answer (score 63):

[`DateUtil.parseDate(dateString)`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/DateUtils.html) from apache http-components

(legacy: [`DateUtil.parseDate(dateString)`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/DateUtil.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String%29) (from apache commons-httpclient))

It has the correct format defined as a Constant, which is guaranteed to be compliant with the protocol.

Comment: BTW, commons-httpclient has been superseded by org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient.

Comment: The class is now org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils   http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/DateUtils.html

Comment: I had to use `org.apache.http.client.utils.DateUtils`, `httpclient-4.3.3`

Comment: DateUtil still uses SimpleDateFormat inside with a ThreadLocal cache. If you are looking also for performance see joda DateTimeFormatter

Answer (score 37):

## java.time

When using the new [Java Date and Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) the code would simply be:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed, 09 Apr 2008 23:55:38 GMT", DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
```

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class pre-defines a constant for that particular format in [`RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME). As the name suggests, [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) defines that format.

Answer (score 25):

RFC 2616 defines three different date formats that a conforming client must understand.

The Apache HttpClient provides a DateUtil that complies with the standard:

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/DateUtils.html

https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/client/utils/DateUtils.java

`Date date = DateUtils.parseDate( headerValue );`

Comment: Just a minor point in case people get confused: the date format RFC is 1123, which is referred to from RFC 2616 here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1

Comment: @Raedwald which itself is superseded by [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `URLConnection`s, there is already a handy method.

See
[URLConnection#getLastModified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getLastModified%28%29)

This method parses the date string and returns a milliseconds value. Then you can happily create a `Date` with that value.

Comment: Note that this method uses the deprecated `Date.parse` method, at least  as of Oracle JDK 7, which _seems_ to support all three HTTP 1.1 [Full Date](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1) formats.