# Unparseable date Exception when passing String date

Tags: java, string, date, time

I am retrieving the Last-Modified value of HTTP response header and attempting to convert the String date value to Date object as:

```
  ..

  URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
  Map<String, List<String>> headers = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
  Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy",   Locale.ENGLISH).parse(headers.get(LAST_MODIFIED).get(0));
```

This is throwing the exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 27 Oct 2011 13:09:24
>   GMT"  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)

Can someone spot the issue with this?! Thanks.

**EDITED**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `urlConnection.getLastModified()` and convert that long to a date or Calendar.

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply the proper pattern to [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

> **E**: Day in week
>   **d**: Day in month
>   **M**: Month in year
>   **y**: Year
>   **H**: Hour in day (0-23)
>   **m**: Minute in hour
>   **s**: Second in minute
>   **z**: Time Zone

```
String dateString = "Thu, 27 Oct 2011 13:09:24 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date d = format.parse(dateString);
```

Take a look at this duplicate question: [How to parse Date from HTTP Last-Modified header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1930158/851811).

Apache [commons-httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) provides [`DateUtil.parseDate(dateString)`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/DateUtil.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String%29) with already uses this format, as Bohzo [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930158/how-to-parse-date-from-http-last-modified-header/1930240#1930240) in his solution to the linked question

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using `urlConnection.getDate()` to retrieve the value of the `Date` header? It looks like your retrieving the `CONTENT_TYPE` header field.

Comment: See Edited. `urlConnection.getDate()` will return current date.

Comment: As the javadoc says: `Returns the value of the date header field.`, That is not the same as the LastModified header.

Answer (score 0):

The date  format you have specified does not match the date format in the string you are parsing.
try:

```
EEE, dd MMM, yyyy
```