# Rails how to return date and time in the RFC 2822 standard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a method which return the time , I want to return the time in `RFC 2822` format please suggest how can I achieve this ?

Comment: One of the practical purpose of formatting in rfc2822 is 'If-Modified-Since' HTTP header. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593796/if-modified-since-date-format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply:

```
require 'time'

t = Time.now
formatted_time = t.rfc2822  # "Wed, 05 Oct 2011 22:26:12 -0400"
```

[More details.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html)