# Testing Spring HTTP Caching

Tags: spring, testing, http-caching

I have springboot application that enable http caching. I'm using `webRequest.checkModifiedSince` as describe in [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-lastmodified). When running my application in browser I get correct result, `200` status code on first hit and `304` on next hit. But when I run maven test to my application it seems that `webRequest.checkModifiedSince` always return false.

Here is my testcase :

```
@Test
public void checkCache() throws Exception {
    MvcResult res = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/resource/to/cache.jpg"))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                        .andReturn();

    String date = res.getResponse().getHeader("Last-Modified");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setIfModifiedSince(Long.parseLong(date));
    headers.setCacheControl("max-age=0");

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("same/resource/as/above.jpg")
                .headers(headers))
                .andExpect(status().isNotModified());
}
```

Did I do something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending conditional HTTP requests, you should usually only send `If-Modified-Since` (using the `Last-Modified` value) and `If-None-Match` (using the `Etag` value).

In this example, you're also sending a `max-age=0` directive which means "don't give me anything that's older than 0 seconds", indeed asking the server to send the response anyway (see [RFC doc about max-age](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.1)). This is typically the kind of directive you'd see in browser requests when doing a "hard refresh".

Remove that directive from the request and the server should respond 304 Not Modified.

Answer (score 1):

The `Last-Modified` header is a string like: `Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT`. So I highly doubt that you can parse them to an `Long`.

*I think that your test is failing because an parse exception.*

```
String dateString = res.getResponse().getHeader("Last-Modified");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date date = format.parse(dateString);
```

@See: [How to parse Date from HTTP Last-Modified header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930158/how-to-parse-date-from-http-last-modified-header)

Comment: Thanks @Ralph. But when i print `res.getResponse().getHeader("Last-Modified")` it gives me `Long` (1434603287000). that's why i use Long.parse. I didn't get any exception, but `webRequest.checkModifiedSince` always return false in mvn test.  Do you have any other solution?