# Communicating with remote server in Android

Tags: android, django, http

As part of the college mini-project, I am developing a micro-blogging platform for Android. I am planning to use Django framework in python to handle the communication between Android and remote server so as to make database API independent. I heard its best practice to use HTTP methods for the communication. Which is the best site/book to learn using HTTP methods for Android? I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard Java HTTP operations.  Check out this SO post: [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

There isn't anything particular about Android in this respect.  Although make sure you include the `android.permissions.INTERNET` permission in your manifest file otherwise it will totally fail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am confused at making a choice between java.net.* package and Apache's HTTPclient. Any suggestions?

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't really know.  I only have experience with the apache one and I have used it on android.  I would suggest the apache one as it's part of Android's library.  A sample open source project I've worked on that used it is http://code.google.com/p/vuphone/source/browse/trunk/projects/wreck-watch-android/src/org/vuphone/wwatch/android/http/HTTPPoster.java