# hitting a URL using java

Tags: java, http, url

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)
>   [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

using java, how do i hit any url?

for instance, opening of http://www.xyz.com/node1 in a browser will tell xyz.com that node1 is hit.
so in this java program (which sends sms text say 'node1' in example above embedded in the url itself to a sms gateway server)

how do i achieve it without opening any browser or using servlet.

Comment: Exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java

Comment: Tutorial: [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: @Sam152: That's a completely different question, dealing with sending an HTTP request.  That's different than just loading a URL.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

But using it directly is overkill if you just want to load the URL in question.  [This guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html) shows you how to open a URL.

Basically it boils down to:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.xyz.com/node1");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use URL http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html. For more advanced/flexible URL fetching you could use HttpClient http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/