# send http request to linux server

Tags: java, c, web-services, http

I have to send an HTTP request to our C programme which is running on a Linux machine. How can I send an HTTP request in Java to our server which is in C and running on a Linux machine?

Comment: The language in which your server is written and the OS it runs on are both irrelevant to this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send HTTP request in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void sendPostRequest() {

    //Build parameter string
    String data = "width=50&height=100";
    try {

        // Send the request
        URL url = new URL("http://www.somesite.com");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        //write parameters
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();

        // Get the response
        StringBuffer answer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            answer.append(line);
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();

        //Output the response
        System.out.println(answer.toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above example is for sending a POST request using a URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to send an HTTP request in Java to a web server written in C, you can use the [`URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) class.

Comment: thanks but  if u give me some complete example then it will be easier for me. I need some more clarification.

Comment: Can any one give the complete code of sending an HTTP request in Java to a web server written in C.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
// Construct data
String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

// Send data
URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/cgi");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();

// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    // Process line...
}
wr.close();
rd.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
```

The above example is for sending a POST request using a URL.
Also take a look at [Sun Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) on reading/Writing from/to a [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html). The other option is to use [Apache HTTPComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) which has examples for the [HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html) and [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) module.
If you are looking into implementing the web Server, you will have to handle the Http request yourselves which involves a thread pool, parsing the requests, generating HTML, security, multiple sessions, etc or follow the easy route by using off-the-shelf web server like Apache and seeing which all high-level languages like Perl, Ruby can be used for developing the web application.
For implementing your own Http server, please take a look at [Micro-Httpd](http://www.acme.com/software/micro_httpd/) or [tinyHttpd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyhttpd/)
You may also want to look at [Adding Web Interface -C++ application](http://dclib.blogspot.com/2007/03/adding-web-interface-to-c-application.html) which has a sample code.

Comment: thanks but i also need a web interface of our server which is written in c

Comment: Meh, I think thats asking a bit much. What code have you tried yourself?

Comment: I am trying for a web interface to  our server which is a programme written in c .

Answer (score 0):

From the way your question is worded.. I think you need to know some basic stuff before you can start. Try try googling for a simple guide to how web servers work.

Once you have the basic idea, there are a couple of options for a C programmer:

1) You want your C program to be running continuously, waiting for a request from your Java.

In this case, you will have to code your C program to open a Socket and Listen for connections. See http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm for example.

OR

2) You have a web Server on your server which will run your C program each time a particular request is made? In this case, you will have to code your C as a CGI program. See http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html for example.

Hint: (2) is much easier!