# Can we create HTTP (GET or POST) request programmatically

Tags: java, http

Can we create a HTTP request (GET or POST) programmatically.

Like in other protocols(ex : SIP) we can create a request programmatically but i have a doubt for HTTP.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643730/httpclient-vs-httpurlconnection for alternatives to java.net.HttpUrlConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible.

Have a look here:
[java.net.HttpUrlConnection](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/pkg.html)

Sample code can also be found there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using [`HTTPURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).