# Easiest way to make http requests in java

Tags: java, maven

I'm looking for a maven artifact or some pre-existing framework that will turn making http requests into a 1 liner. For those familiar with Ruby, I'm thinking about something alomg the lines of Httparty which supports get, put, post... etc.

ex:

```
Response response = SomeLibrary.get("https://api.google.com/maps")
int code = response.code
String body = response.body
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send HTTP request in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

Comment: You can forget about one-liners, it seems :) All the suggestions below are trying to be very complete implementations. But I'd suggest starting with the JDK's `HttpUrlConnection` and writing your own small API around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Url.openConnection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) and [HttpUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 2):

we use apache commons http

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It is very easy and supports many functions altough it is not a one liner.