# Java equivalent Curl

Tags: java, curl

```
curl -d 'user[name]=huck&user[email]=huck@xyz.com''http://sandbox.v2.xyz.com/api/berl/a4be95e6f86/users.json'
```

can anyone tell me how we will be able to run this curl command.

Another thing if i  run it through java what will be the java equivalent to this call?
it is basically a call to rest service

Comment: If it is rest call, may be HttpURLConnection API will be helpful.http://digiassn.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-simple-httpurlconnection-example.html

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java -- you want to send an HTTP request and read the response.

Comment: Even Better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

You have two choiches:

1. Using something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/).
2. Using something like [apache exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html)