# Java Post to Localhost PHP Server

Tags: java, php, http-post

I have a java script that generates strings on my data. Is there any way I can use POST on my Xampp Localhost PHP to receive the data string from the java program and echo it out on my PHP page?

Comment: you want to do post from java or javascript..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) object to make a request to localhost. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java) and [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).