# XML request/response in Java

Tags: java, xml, api

I have an API which I want to use to fetch data. For fetching data I have to send a request in XML format and response will be sent in XML. Does anyone have any example how to send a request using Java and how to decode the response in java.

Comment: Your question is too vague as for me...
Are you talking about web services? What API is based on? Maybe its just an http connection to soe servlet? Please elaborate a little

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on how you want to send a request via XML? It can be done by POST, SOAP, AIM SIM etc... And to what - web service, web page.. Checkout the javax.xml.soap package

Comment: @BenSewards POST ..I have a URL for the application and it accepts POST requests in XML format.

Comment: @yogsma you can use the OutputStreamWriter for sending a POST requesting using a URL: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i have just what you wanted... but i would ask you to use the following APIs ...

- `JAXP` and `JAXB`
- `Castor`

**-** The below code snippet method accepts the `url` of the web-server and the `xmlQuery`

**-** I have used the `NameValuePair` to send the XML request

**-** Please **replace** the `MySSLSocketFactory.getNewHttpClient();` with an `Http` Client, i have used this it needs a custom certificate to access this site.`

**Here is the code from my Project, that sends an XML req and gets back an XML resp :**

```
public String postData(String url, String xmlQuery) {

        final String urlStr = url;
        final String xmlStr = xmlQuery;
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                HttpClient httpclient = MySSLSocketFactory.getNewHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);

                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlStr));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    Log.d("Vivek", response.toString());

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream i = entity.getContent();

                    Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String s = null;

                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        Log.d("YumZing", s);
                        sb.append(s);
                    }

                    Log.d("Check Now", sb + "");

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }

        });

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method " + sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following discussion, [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)
For the response in xml, make sure that the mime-type is set to application/xml.
Hope this answers your question.