# how to send HTTP request to a servlet

Tags: java, swing, tomcat, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

I only have one servlet running on the Tomcat server side. Now I want to send a HTTP request to this servlet from a Swing application, and it's not an APPLET application (because I see some examples sending request from applet). How can I do this?

Comment: *"I see some examples sending request from applet"*  It is much the same when done from an applet, command-line application or servlet.  Try using the applet based example and get back to us with a specific question if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

While you can open a direct socket connection and send the raw HTTP headers & content and receive a response back, I would urge you to take a look at [HttpRequestBase](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase.html).