# HTTP request on Android

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I am totally, desperate, that is why I am asking you for help. I have the following code in an android application:

```
public void OnButtonClick(View view) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, Exception
{       
    URL yahoo = new URL("http://privyrobsi.sk/brigades/getBrigades.json");
    URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    EditText ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) ET.setText(ET.getText()+inputLine);         
    in.close();        
}
```

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359702/2358887), I only modified it a little.
When I try to run the code as a stand-alone java application, it works. But when I try to use it in android, the emulator says that the unfortunately, the application stopped.
I saved the Log from LogCat [here](http://www.beetxt.com/printable.php?view=qCK).
I also have uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" in my manifest file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can not perform network operation in main thread. Perform this in a [asynctask](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html&ei=2RuJUZiuGZCrrAeW3YH4Bw&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bmk).

**Update:**

Your logcat data shows you have a NetworOnMainThreadException. According to [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

**Solution:**

As I have already mentioned you have to use a different thread to perform Network operations. You can use the following

1. Asynctask
2. Differet worker thread
3. Handler

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception/6343299#6343299). The answers of this question cover almost all the solutions