# how to make http request same url with different ip's?

Tags: java, ip, httprequest, urlrequest

I would like to send an HTTP request and get the response body, but I have URL that is stored on multiple servers. Let's say I have this list:

```
www.mysite.com 192.168.1.31
www.mysite.com 192.168.1.32
```

and I want to make the request to all the the different servers (different IP's) but same URL

Is there any option to do that in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.  Define the URL as being what you want and using the IP address in place of a domain name.  I.E. `http://192.168.1.31/path/to/index.html`  Then add the "Host: www.mysite.com" header before issuing the request.  Any HTTP/1.1 compliant server will use the value of that header as the domain with which it was accessed.

Exactly *how* you accomplish this depends on whatever library you're using to make the connection but they should all have the ability to set arbitrary headers -- just make sure it doesn't overwrite your custom "Host" header with one of its own from the URL.  See [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java) for examples of how to implement an HTTP request.

This works because on the wire it's all IP.  You can try it yourself using [nc](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/), socket, or even telnet.

```
(open TCP connection to 192.168.1.31 port 80)
GET /path/to/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
                                        <--blank line signals end of headers
```