# Java Equivalent to C# Stream Write() (HttpWebRequest -> HttpURLConnection)

Tags: c#, java

```
public static Response callService(String strURL, String RequestBody, String Token, int timeout, Boolean isPostMethod) {

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);

    httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestBody), 0, RequestBody.Length);
}
```

What is the equivalent of the following code in JAVA?

```
httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestBody), 0, RequestBody.Length);
```

I'm using:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

which is the JAVA equivalent to .NET's HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to achieve, not what you would do in another language.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java

Comment: @Pete Yes that helped, I guess it's the same as using: DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    dos.writeBytes(RequestBody);
    dos.flush();
    dos.close(); If you can post it as an answer so I mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been addressed in a few SO posts. There's actually a tutorial of sorts here:

[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

That's probably the single best source I've seen on the topic as it provides extensive details on performing and handling an HTTP Request in Java.

There's also this question: [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

And finally, it's all based on the HttpUrlConnection class which is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html