# How to get data from MySQL and store it to Java program using PHP script and JSON

Tags: java, php, mysql, json

I want to create Java application that will recieve data from MySQL and store it to the list, but for the beginning storing to the JTextArea would be fine.

I have database with tables on the localhost, and PHP script that when it's activated, gets data from table "orders" and returns data in JSON.

```
<?php
    /*
 * Following code will list all orders
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from orders table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT* FROM orders") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["orders"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $order = array();
        $order["id"] = $row["id"];
        $order["tablle"] = $row["tablle"];
        $order["drink"] = $row["drink"];
        $order["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["orders"], $order);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);;
}
?>
```

When I test it on the localhost, it works fine, but I don't know how to call this php script from java and take that text formatted in JSON and store it in the JTextArea in Java.

I don't know much about JSON. Sorry, noob here.

Java class:

```
package newpackage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Prozor extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    JButton dugme = new JButton("Get data");

    public Prozor(){
        this.setBounds(500, 200, 500, 500);
        this.setTitle("naslov");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        ta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,400));
        panel.add(ta);
        panel2.add(dugme);

        dugme.addActionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(dugme)) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prozor p = new Prozor();
        p.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you'll need a HTTP client connection from Java to the server that serves the php output. You can find hundreds of libraries and ways of doing that if you do some research.

Comment: Don't use any `success` key, just encode the empty array (`[]`) when there are no results ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you'll have to do.

1. Invoke the php script from Java

   To do this you'll need to know what the URL for the script is, this includes the `protocol`, `port`, `host` and `path`. In other words something like: `http://localhost:8000/orders.php`. Once you have the URL, you'll need to [make an HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java) to it.
2. Parse the response into a JSON data structure.

   You can do this using an existing library like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
3. Use the `JSONObject` to populate your UI

   Figure out how you want to display the data and call `setText` on your `JTextArea`