# Check if my server is up via java

Tags: java, tomcat

I am starting a tomcat server in my local for a web application and it takes around 20 minutes to be up and running. I want to check if the web app is up and running and taking any requests via java. Any help? 
My server is say at localhost:8001/myapp

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious, why does it take 20 minutes?

Comment: Any hints in the logfile of the webserver?

Comment: There are many ways: issue a dummy HTTP GET and check for one expected answer (say, call home or a status page, expecting 200 as status), etc.

Comment: Lets just say its a huge webapp :P , I do have multiple webservices hosted via it. any options there?

Comment: One more thing, I want to avoid making any changes to my webapp.

Comment: This does the trick

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java

thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

You can check it through many ways. Like... Set a servlet as start up on-load and inside it keep some loggers which files log messages along with exact time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like `localhost:8001/myapp/status` to the app that would return information about current status. Then you can just sent http request from java and check the response

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String execute(String uri) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer outputLine = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        outputLine.append(inputLine);
    in.close();
    return outputLine.toString();
}
```

I guess I will call this method after a certain time period to see if I'm getting a timeout exception of the raw html.