# Using HttpsUrlConnection to access Google Geocoding service

Tags: java, ssl, google-geocoder, httpsurlconnection

I am in the process of building a series of web services in Java which, among other things, will be relying on Google's Geocoding Maps API to convert physical addresses into latitude and longitude points.

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses), the geocoding service can be accessed by doing a simple GET, e.g. the following URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Here `YOUR_API_KEY` would be replaced by the actual key corresponding to your app.

Coming to the actual question, I am planning to use `HttpsUrlConnection` in Java to make the GET call.  However, I am confused about which certificate I should be trusting.  Is it safe to simply trust all certificates, or should I be installing a Google SSL certificate into my trust store, and only trust that?  I read on Stack Overflow about man-in-the-middle attacks, but I don't know if they be a possibility here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends.

Is the Google SSL certificate signed by a will known [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA)?

If so, that SSL certificate should be in the default truststore that ships with Java and you will not need to do anything to trust that certificate.

If not, then you will need to specifically trust the Google SSL certificate.

I personally use the [InstallCert](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) program to download and install certificates to the default Java Truststore.

**EDIT**

Here is some example code for you:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class GoogleMapsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("https://maps.google.com/");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        rd.close();
    }
}
```

The above code was inspired by, er (mostly) stolen from [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java) and How to use [HttpURLConnection POST data to web server?](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139)

Comment: FWIW, the Google SSL certificate for https://maps.google.api/ is signed by "Google Internet Authority G2" which is chained by "GeoTrust Global CA".  Taking a quick peek at the truststore (cacerts) that shipped with a recently downloaded version of Java, "GeoTrust Global CA" is in that truststore and you should be good to go.

Comment: I will test your answer and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: Added some example code that you should be able to run.  BTW, I would strongly recommend that you look into using HttpClient, using HttpURLConnection is awful.

Comment: I was able to make the GET call using code which somewhat resembled what you gave me.  You were correct that Java ships with a trust manager which trusts Google Maps.