# How to write a client for REST web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I am trying to write a client for REST web Services; I am using Tomcat application server. All the below packages are not being supported.

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
```

I am new to REST, which dependency should I add to pom.xml for these libraries?

```
package com.abc.client;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class JaxRSClient {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // Creating the client
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(
            "http://localhost:8080/jersey/RestWebService/HelloREST/"
        );
        System.out.println(target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with HttpURLConnection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send HTTP request in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

Comment: check http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api

Answer (score 3):

You have all those classes in [javax.ws.rs-api](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.ws.rs%7Cjavax.ws.rs-api%7C2.0.1%7Cjar)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But this is only the API, you will need to choose your `JAX-RS` implementation such as [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) (you can get the full list of existing implementations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services)).

If you want to use `Jersey`, you will need to add only the next dependency to your pom file, indeed `javax.ws.rs-api` is already a dependency of `jersey-client`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Nicholas - If I am using Tomcat application server, will jersey-client dependency as mentioned above work ?

Comment: @Ridhi if you use Tomcat, you can verify it on localhost with the jersey client code. I successfully compiled and run your code with the Maven dependencies shown in this answer, and it tries to connect as expected.

Comment: yes sir, but it won't be provided as Tomcat is not really an application server but more a servlet engine, you will have to put the libs into tomcat/lib