# How to get json from external URL

Tags: java, json

I'm using maven in Java with a jersey client, and I'm trying to retrieve JSON from an external URl. A GET request is invoked when a user enters a city whichs build the URL as follows. The CITY is a PathParam

If the user enters London this is the generated URL -> http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=XXXxxxxx

If you enter the url above in the browser the JSON returns there, which is great, as I'm getting somewhere. But I don't no how to data from the external link and parse it (GSON maybe?)

My code for getting the city is as follows

```
@Path("/WeatherAPI")
public class Weather {
  @GET
  @Path("/{City}")
  public Response getWeather(@PathParam("City") String City) {

    String APIURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=";
    String APIKey = "XXXXxxxx";
    String FullUrl = APIURL + City + "&&appid=" + APIKey;

    return Response.status(200).entity(FullUrl).build();
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean you don't know how to run the request from your server to the provider of the json response?

Comment: Yes basically. @Juan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java

Comment: Gson doesn't do HTTP requests. Only parsing the JSON.

Comment: Look into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html. T

Comment: Still lost here. Any tutorials, or guidelines/

Comment: here is a tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Comment: My issue is though, the response i get from the server is "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&&appid=177a4cf0dea72bacc915c0a90eb7b1ac". But how do I go into that link and take out the json

Comment: replace your url with the one on "Java client to send a “GET” request." section and run and see what you get

Answer (score 1):

In case you still struggling with this one, found another java http client...it seems easier, http://unirest.io/java.html, just include the dependencies listed:

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class QuickSOQ {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnirestException {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.get("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=XXXxxxxx")
          //.routeParam("method", "get")
          //.queryString("name", "Mark")
          .asJson();

        System.out.println(jsonResponse.getBody());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### To get the response from the HTTP response you would need to do this:

```
    public void getHTTPResponse() {

            try {
                URL url = validateAddress(
                        "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=XXXxxxxx"); 
                 //validate url using some method to escape any reserved characters


                BufferedReader reader = null;

                HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //create the connection and open it
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                // start reading the response given by the HTTP response

                StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();

                // using string builder as it is more efficient for append operations
                String line;
                // append the string response to our jsonString variable
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonString.append(line);
                }
                // dont forget to close the reader
                reader.close();
                // close the http connection
                httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
                // start parsing
                parseJSON();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Malformed URL or issues with the reader.");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

### Parsing the JSON using GSON

```
private void parseJSON() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // let GSON do the work
    SomeObject[] fromJSON = gson.fromJson(jsonString, SomeObject[].class);
    // add to our list or do whatever else you want from here onwards.
    ArrayList<SomeObject> o= new ArrayList<SomeObject>(Arrays.asList(fromJSON));
}
```

### How to get GSON

Include the following in your maven pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Or if you are using gradle do this

```
    dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    }
```

Don't forget to use mavenCentral() as the repository.

If you're not using maven or gradle - I recommend you do. It will make managing your APIs much **much** easier than downloading JARs etc.

(Just noticed OP is using maven, but I'll leave it in for others)

Hope this helped.

Comment: My code in the OP is in a file called Weather.java. Where would i put the above code. I usually don't use Java, more of a php/node guy. So i'm very confused

Comment: I would put the above code in a class separate away from code that does anything else. Create a class which has the sole responsibility of getting data from the RESTful API. This will help with maintenance and the general structure of the program.

Comment: Then have a getter method which can be used to access the data retrieved from outside the class.