# Get members list using Google Stackdriver API

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, stackdriver

I am developping the function that request member list from [Google Stackdriver API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.groups.members/list)

I am using library fallowing code using gradle.

gradle.build

```
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-monitoring:0.42.1-beta'
```

for example, Getting group list is following code.(JAVA)

```
GroupServiceClient groupServiceClient = GroupServiceClient.create();

ListGroupsRequest request = ListGroupsRequest.newBuilder()
            .setName("projects/" + projectId)
            .build();

ListGroupsPagedResponse response = groupServiceClient.listGroups(request);

response.iterateAll();
```

like above code, i can get group list using google monitoring libarary

but, there is no method that get member list in group

is there way to get member list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use example shown in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.groups.members/list#embedded-explorer) for Java where it shows how to build the list

```
Monitoring.Projects.Groups.Members.List request = monitoringService.projects().groups().members().list(name);
ListGroupMembersResponse response;
```

then

```
response = request.execute();
```

and then inside a for loop get the members

```
MonitoredResource monitoredResource : response.getMembers()
```

Comment: your code import from [google-api-services-moniroing](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-monitoring). But my code import from [google cloud monitoring](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-monitoring) which don't have Members Class. Do you know different that librarys @Nakilon

Comment: You can use a workaround and perform an HTTP request[ 1] for this endpoint: (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.groups.members/list)
You will receive a JSON as a response which you can parse [2].

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java/1359702#1359702                                                       
[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa