# What is the best way to make an HTTP request from a Java program?

Tags: java, sql, json, http

I'm attempting to use a small Java program to make an HTTPs request (sending plain text of an SQL command) and trying to receive JSON data. Is this capability built into Java already or will I need external packages/libraries?

Comment: Sending plain SQL commands is not a good idea. That way, everyone can just modify or delete your database if they want

Comment: I have the connection established using a token, so I'm the only one able to modify it as of right now. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to work the HTTP POST request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://square.github.io/okhttp/ is a good library for http interaction. Then you can use Jackson/Gson to parse the response to a typed object if you want

Usage

> ```
> public static final MediaType JSON
>     = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
>
> OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
>
> String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
>   RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
>   Request request = new Request.Builder()
>       .url(url)
>       .post(body)
>       .build();
>   Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
>   return response.body().string();
> }
> ```

Maven:

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
>   <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
>   <version>2.4.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

or Gradle:

> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

If you want to kill an ant with a Patton Tank, you have all sort of other options like spring, netflix OSS - feign client + ribbon etc

That being said, first, I would try out what Kayaman posted, https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client as its one less dependency.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things you can do. When I normally need to use HTTP requests, I use the [Jsoup parser](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup), as it can send HTTP requests in a simple one-liner:

```
Jsoup.connect("google.com").data("key", "value").post();
```

You can get JSON responses with Jsoup by using [ignoreContentType(true)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#ignoreContentType-boolean-):

```
Jsoup.connect("https://postman-echo.com/post").data("derp1", "derp2").data("sql1", "sql2").ignoreContentType(true).post().body().html()
```

which results in this output:

```
{
   "args":{

   },
   "data":"",
   "files":{

   },
   "form":{
      "derp1":"derp2",
      "sql1":"sql2"
   },
   "headers":{
      "host":"postman-echo.com",
      "content-length":"21",
      "accept":"text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2",
      "accept-encoding":"gzip",
      "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
      "x-forwarded-port":"443",
      "x-forwarded-proto":"https"
   },
   "json":{
      "derp1":"derp2",
      "sql1":"sql2"
   },
   "url":"https://postman-echo.com/post"
}
```

From there, just parse the String as JSON using whatever JSON api you'd like (I personally use [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)). You can look more into the Jsoup API at the documentation located [here](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/overview-summary.html).

If you'd like to refrain from utilizing APIs, [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) may be able to assist you better than I can, as it shows how to send a POST request utilizing both HTTPSUrlConnection, as well as Apache's HTTPClient.