# How the HTTP Request/Reply server side is written?

Tags: javascript, java, php, web, server

I have found this links   [How to send HTTP request GET/POST in Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) , [How to SEND HTTP request in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

i understand this but this is from the client side , how it should be implemented in the server side ?

What is need is to use the link in the client side for example

http://linktomywebsite//(a parameter sent from each client)

and based on the parameter he gets response

Comment: This is a very broad question. I would research how to write an API, because that is what you would need to write to handle those requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you start learning how to create REST APIs with Java Servlets. It will help you understand exactly how the server side works. Here’s a step by step example https://www.theserverside.com/video/Step-by-step-RESTful-web-service-example-in-Java-using-Eclipse