# Java request for marking elasticsearch index block as null

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am facing cluster block exception due to lack of space on elastic search node. But after sufficient space is available I need to manually set the "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null value using java high level rest client. Same I am able to do with Kibana but need some java equivalent of that.
Kibana request :

```
PUT /_settings
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
```

Elastic version : 6.8.4
Java : 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the High Level Rest Client has no Support for his feature, you need to use the [Low Level Rest Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-low-usage-requests.html) or [issue the http request by yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

Comment: Used Low level rest client to perform request.