# How to send HTTP request in JAVA 16.0

Tags: java, http, post, get, request

As I can see after Java 11 HttpURLRequest was substituted by HttpRequest.

How can I send a simple HTTP request using HttpRequest?

Comment: Doesn't the JavaDoc on class `HttpRequest` help already? It basically tells you to use `HttpClient` and `HttpRequest.builder()`.

Comment: I think you mean `HttpURLConnection`.  It wasn't replaced.  It is still available for applications to use as of Java 17.  It hasn't been marked as deprecated.  (As JEP 110 states: "This API is intended to **eventually** replace the` HttpURLConnection` API **for new code**...")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send HTTP request in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

A simple GET request using JDK 11 HttpClient + HttpRequest:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .build();

HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://pathHere"))
        .GET().build();


client.send(req, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();
```