# How to parse a XML behind a standard http authorization (Android)

Tags: android, xml-parsing, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-authentication, apache-commons-httpclient

I've got an XML file on a server. It is protected with an standard Http-Authorization. I want to parse the file. So what is the right way to get the file to the parser?

The authentification string I already have (Base64).

The XML looks like:

```
    <action>
      <class>11/1,11/2,11/3,11/4/ lat1</class>
      <hour>1</hour>
      <lesson>Eng</lesson>
      <teacher>Schr</teacher>
      <room>E312</room>
      <info>for Lat Gri </info>
    </action>
    <action>
      <class>11/1,11/2,11/3,11/4/ lat1</class>
      <hour>2</hour>
      <lesson>Eng</lesson>
      <teacher>Schr</teacher>
      <room>E312</room>
      <info>for Lat Gri </info>
    </action>
```

Comment: What's wrong with requesting the file with the `Authorization` header set?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am really new to this and don't know how to do that. I already looked up many examples but none worked for me...               Edit: Do you mean [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627395/http-requests-with-basic-authentication)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To request a resource over HTTP using [Basic Authentication](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#BasicAA), you need to construct and add the `Authorization` header line to the request as described in the linked document.

Basically, you add a header line to the request. The name of the field is `Authorization` and the value is the auth type followed by a space and then the base64 encoded string of the `username:password`.

So for e.g. if the username is John and the password is secret, you would form a string:

> John:secret

and then base64 encode it which will result in:

> Sm9objpzZWNyZXQ=

So the full header line to add to the request looks like this:

> Authorization: Basic Sm9objpzZWNyZXQ=

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you meane something like `HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://mysitewithbasicauth.com/test.xml");
   httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic c2NodWVsZXI6aGapbmU3NA==");` and then I end up with a HttpEntity.

Comment: I don't know this HttpClient you are working with, but given the header is added _before_ the request is sent, it should be fine.

Comment: Bascially I don't have anything yet. I need to know how to do it, because I'm only a beginner... sorry

Comment: Just try. The example in the above comment looks OK.