# pinnaclesports api basic auth with java

Tags: java, api

When trying to get account balance used api I got an exception:

> ```
> IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: 
> https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/client/balance
> ```

Here's the code:

```
public void getBalance() throws Exception{

    byte[] bytes = "username:password".getBytes("UTF-8");
    String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
    System.out.println(encoded);
    URL api = new URL("https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/client/balance");
    URLConnection apiConnection = api.openConnection();
    apiConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(apiConnection.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();

}
```

Comment: Please give the full stack trace from the exception.

Comment: Do you know what a 401 error code is?

Answer (score 0):

I think your authentication is broken or not set properly. The API uses *Basic Auth* and a Base64 encoded username/password pair. You should read http://www.pinnaclesports.com/en/api/manual#authentication and make sure that your authorization is correct.

Here's an explanation for HTTP status code 401:

> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication
>   is possible but has failed or not yet been provided. The response
>   must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `Authenticator`, like this:

```
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());
        }
    });
    URL api = new URL("https://api.pinnaclesports.com/v1/client/balance");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(api.openStream()));
```

Or if that doesn't work, then try using an `HttpURLConnection` instead of `URLConnection`,
like this:

```
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

You might also find [this related post helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628326/641955), using Apache Commons.