# Java httpClient 4.3.6 basic Authentication with complete URI and scheme

Tags: java, authentication, basic-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

**What I want:** 
Send a GET request with a preemtive bassic authentication.

The request looks about like this:

```
<startURL>/app/process?job=doSomething&param=value1,value2
```

whereas startURL is always a https link depends on the enviroment.

Looks something like this:
    https://testABC.com
    https://prodABC.com

startURL is also placed in a properties file as is for the diffrent enviroments.

**What I looked into:**
http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-use-basic-authentication.html

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

It all contains a

```
 HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("hostname", portnumber, "scheme");
```

Which is what I am having trouble with. This method is also the only one that lets you specify the scheme as "https". 
One issue is, hat I don't know the portnumber. I think (?) I probably could just specify -1 for the default port, to make it work, but even aside that I also don't have the hostname, only the above mentioned startURL. I don't really want to parse this extra each time, while I also don't really want to add another property, just for the hostname.

I digged around and found this snippet, which looks like just what I want:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://foo.com/bar");
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
 new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"),
 "UTF-8", false));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

from [HTTP requests with basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627395/http-requests-with-basic-authentication)

It gives the complete request URL and simply adds the basic header and does not need any port specified. Only that this is now deprecated since Version 4.2:

```
Deprecated. (4.2) Use ContextAwareAuthScheme.authenticate( Credentials, HttpRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
```

I couldn't find a single example for this method to return the basic auth header. It also wants a context as a parameter, which above snipped doesn't have. I really have no real clue how this is supposed to be used.

**So, what i want to know concretely:**

I just want to set up a request with the complete link, that contains all that there is, like:

```
https://testABC.com/app/process?job=doSomething&param=value1,value2
```

and just give this as a parameter for a request that does preemptive basic authentication.

Is there any way to do this without digging up the deprecated methods and how does it look like?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem as yours.

What worked for me is the following:

```
UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "12345");

HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://foo.bar.com/rest");
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("foo.bar.com", 443, "https");
  CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
  credsProvider.setCredentials(
          new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
          creds);
  credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,creds);

 // Create AuthCache instance
  AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
 // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
  BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
  authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

 // Add AuthCache to the execution context
  HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
context.setAuthCache(authCache);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(targetHost, get, context);
```

And I found this solution on: [HttpClientBuilder basic auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914311/httpclientbuilder-basic-auth)

Comment: Would not have helped, because the HttpHost constructor needs the port specified and the hostname. But as mentioned above I only had the startUrl and explicitly wanted to avoid parsing and breaking it down onto these three argument values.

Comment: In my case, creating header your way didn't work though I found that the same Authorization header content was set as Base64. For some reason, the Base64 Authorization set by using httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
 new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"),
 "UTF-8", false)) worked and not the one set manually which resulted in 401. Anyway setting this should be simpler as in 4.1.x

Comment: Tried serval versions from stackoverflow and this post is the only one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I wound up writing the header manually on my own and sending things with that:

```
    String header = "Basic ";       
    String headerValue = "username" + ":" + "password";
    String encodedHeaderValue = Base64.encodeBase64String(headerValue.getBytes());      
    String headerBasic =  header + encodedHeaderValue;

    Header authHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization", headerBasic);
      ArrayList<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
      headers.add(authHeader);  

    ArrayList<Header> headers = getHttpHeaders();
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();

    HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get().setUri(uri).build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```