# get youtube redirected link from short link

Tags: java, android, youtube

When i click url:

```
https://youtu.be/rCiqxFuRi6o?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent
```

It redirects to

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCiqxFuRi6o&feature=youtu.be&rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent
```

How to get programatically from android app this redirected link?

I want finally to get youtube video id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java, android, resolve an url, get redirected uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204599/java-android-resolve-an-url-get-redirected-uri)

Answer (score 1):

when you connect to 
https://youtu.be/rCiqxFuRi6o?rel=0&wmode=transparent

you'll get http 302 status (redirection) :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 14:25:38 GMT
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
Location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCiqxFuRi6o&feature=youtu.be
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

so you just need to read the Location header from the http response header.