# JaxWS: Webservice with Basic Authentication

Tags: web-services, soap, intellij-idea, jax-ws, basic-authentication

I'm building a client for a SOAP webservice. I auto-generated most of the client code with IntelliJ IDEA, by telling it to build a JaxWS webservice client from a WSDL.

The webservice runs on different URLs (test, integration, production), so I need to be able to configure the service URL in my client. My code looks like this:

```
String urlString = props.getProperty(URL);
service = new RequestMultiTransportService(new URL(urlString),
              new QName("http://some.uri.com/",
                        "RequestMultiTransportService"));
Boolean useBasicAuth = Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty(BASICAUTH));
RequestMultiTransport rmt = service.getRequestMultiTransportPort();
if (useBasicAuth) {
    String user = props.getProperty(AUTHUSER);
    String pw   = props.getProperty(AUTHPW);
    Map requestContext = ((BindingProvider)rmt).getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, user);
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, pw);
}
ProvisioningResponse response = rmt.send("some", "params", "...");
```

As you can see, the service might need basic authentication. And here's the problem: While I can configure basic authentication for the actual request, I cannot configure it for loading the WSDL file (which happens in the constructor of `RequestMultiTransportService`). `RequestMultiTransportService` is autogenerated by IDEA, and its constructor just calls its super constructor, being the one of `javax.xml.ws.Service`.

So whereever the webservice requires basic authentication, my code fails, because it does not provide a user / password for fetching the WSDL file located at `urlString`. A possible workaround I thought of is to store the WSDL file locally and point to it with a `file://` URL. But this does not fulfill my requirements, because the service location defined in the WSDL file varies, and I don't seem to be able to change the service URL in the `service` object which has been loaded from the WSDL file.

Has anyone a solution for getting the WSDL file with basic authentication?

Comment: Well, is JAX-WS cannot do it it looks like a bug (most relevant I was able to find is [JAX_WS-1](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-1?focusedCommentId=15246#action_15246)). As JAX-WS will use `URLConnection` at the end of the day, the possible workaround is to use [`Authenticator`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/496707/267197).

Comment: This may be possible, but the problem is that the workaround will set a global property, which will possibly interfere with other services that run in the same environment.

Comment: Just fire a bug for JAX-WS. Perhaps this is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new constructor to your WebServiceClient and pass the username, the password and the endpoint location (that varies) as parameter to it. After this put

```
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, user);
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, pw);
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointUrl);
```

into the requestContext and make sure you will not access the defaultConstructor.

Comment: How do I access the requestContext in the constructor? Wouldn't I need to call `super.getPort()` (which I suppose won't work befor initialization is finished)? And if I don't call the super-Constructor, wouldn't that mean that the client doesn't load the WSDL file at all?