# Exception when implementing JAX-WS client with transport level security

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, webservice-client, transport-security

I am trying to invoke method via webservice (SOAP)

I have generated Web service client with JAX-WS.

I can access the webservice only with transport level security.

I am getting the error:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://10.99.36.26:8001/DummySubsForNetwork?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://10.99.36.26:8001/DummySubsForNetwork?wsdl.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:162)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mirs.sbn.esb.client.DummySubsForNetwork_Service.<init>(DummySubsForNetwork_Service.java:67)
    at main.executeEsbRequest(main.java:167)
    at main.testEsb(main.java:141)
    at main.main(main.java:59)
```

this is my code:

**Main method which I am executing:**

```
private static DummySubsForNetwork executeEsbRequest()
    {

        DummySubsForNetwork_Service service = new DummySubsForNetwork_Service();

        DummySubsForNetwork dummyPort = service.getDummySubsForNetworkSOAP();

        Map<String, Object> rc = ((BindingProvider) dummyPort).getRequestContext();

        rc.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                "http://some.local.ip:8001/DummySubsForNetwork?wsdl");
        rc.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "csmuser");
        rc.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "passw0rd");

        return dummyPort;

    }
```

**Auto generated class via JAX-WS:**

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "DummySubsForNetwork", targetNamespace = "http://www.example.org/DummySubsForNetwork/", wsdlLocation = "http://some.local.ip:8001/DummySubsForNetwork?wsdl")
public class DummySubsForNetwork_Service extends Service
{

    private final static URL DUMMYSUBSFORNETWORK_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(com.mirs.sbn.esb.client.DummySubsForNetwork_Service.class.getName());

    static
    {
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
            URL baseUrl;
            baseUrl = com.mirs.sbn.esb.client.DummySubsForNetwork_Service.class.getResource(".");
            url = new URL(baseUrl, "http://some.local.ip:8001/DummySubsForNetwork?wsdl");
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            logger
                    .warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: 'some.local.ip:8001/DummySubsForNetwork?wsdl', retrying as a local file");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        DUMMYSUBSFORNETWORK_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public DummySubsForNetwork_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName)
    {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public DummySubsForNetwork_Service()
    {
        super(DUMMYSUBSFORNETWORK_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName(
                "http://www.example.org/DummySubsForNetwork/", "DummySubsForNetwork"));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return returns DummySubsForNetwork
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "DummySubsForNetworkSOAP")
    public DummySubsForNetwork getDummySubsForNetworkSOAP()
    {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://www.example.org/DummySubsForNetwork/",
                "DummySubsForNetworkSOAP"), DummySubsForNetwork.class);
    }
}
```

---

I am getting the execption when I am invoking this method in the class: 'DummySubsForNetwork_Service'

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "DummySubsForNetworkSOAP")
    public DummySubsForNetwork getDummySubsForNetworkSOAP()
    {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://www.example.org/DummySubsForNetwork/",
                "DummySubsForNetworkSOAP"), DummySubsForNetwork.class);
    }
```

thanks,
ray.

Comment: I think I've hit the same problem mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296636) and perhaps my comment in that post will help you.

Comment: Does your client works from command line or inside an AppServer? The Authenticator solution worked for me for apps in command line, but not inside WebSphere. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267218/jax-ws-ibm-client-consuming-net-ws-with-active-directory-authentication-ntlm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented the solution for this issue was using:

Authenticator:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java/496707#496707.](http://Authenticator)

ray.