# JAX-WS IBM client consuming .Net WS with Active Directory authentication (NTLM)

Tags: .net, active-directory, websphere, jax-ws, ntlm

I want to consume .Net WS from IBM WebSphere.

I created a WS-client with JAX-WS IBM implementation that consumes a .Net WS on IIS. The client is on SUSE and the authentication is by NTLM with Windows Server 2003 Active Directory.

- If the client is executed in command line the implementation calls java.net.Authenticator to get the credentials and the request is succesful.
- If the client is executed inside RAD the Authenticator is not called and it fails with 401.
- If the client is executed inside WebSphere the Authenticator is not called and it fails with 401.
- If I create an HttpConnection directly to the .Net WS URL the Authenticator is called and the request is succesful.
- If instead of JAX-WS IBM implementation I use the Axis2 (directly, not IBM Axis2 JAX-WS implementation) I could pass to the Axis2 client the Authenticator object and the request is succesful. This only works for NTLM protocol with Windows Server 2003. When we migrate to Windows Server 2008 the auth protocol is NTLMv2 (everybody is moving to NTLMv2 because security issues with NTLM) and the request fails because NTLMv2 is not supported by the HTTP Client 3.X that is the dependency of Axis2. And for some time they are not going to migrate.

If I use other implemetation of JAX-WS than IBM I loose the console administration and the automatic annotation reading, plus to loose support from IBM.

**Questions**

I don´t get why inside of RAD it didn´t work, is the same program that works from command line.

How do you make JAX-WS IBM implementation authenticate with NTLMv2 protocol support with specific credentials? (java.net.Authenticator provides you with this, and it should be called ... it does not)

Is the any way to make IBM JAX-WS implemetation to use another HTTP client than the standard one?

Even the IBM JVM implementation provides NTLM auth (this is the reason why the command line and the direct HttpConnection executions works) so I don´t get why they don´t use it for the IBM WS stack.

**Plus points**

Is there any good way to provide bidirectional ability to consume WS with the ActiveDirectory authentication?

**Comment**

Spring WS uses HttpClient 4.X that supports NTLMv2 auth, but I need a JAX-WS implementation and it **should** be the IBM one. The IBM JAX-WS only seems to support Basic AUTH. I don´t get how the Microsoft WS interop is not important for IBM.

**References**

*Authenticator conf:*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html#setDefault%28java.net.Authenticator%29

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5994706/14811

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, this is what I did.

I create the JAXB objects with the RAD plugin to create a JAX-WS client. I use the generated DTOs as the messages that I pass to the Spring WS library. Spring WS 2.1 comes with Http Client 4.2 that brings NTLMv2 support.

I created an small library to make this process easier, but the procedure idea is:

1. Generate the JAX-WS client with RAD
2. Create a class that implements the service interface generated by RAD
3. For each interface method:
4. 3.1 Inject the interface method's parameters to the JAXB object
5. 3.2 Pass this object to the `WebServiceTemplate` (Spring object) web service call.
6. 3.3 Cast the call response to the JAXB method response object
7. 3.4 Return the inner value of the response object

So, what you finally do is reuse the object generation for a JAX-WS client to wrap the service method's parameters into the object that Spring WS needs to make the call.

For NTLM authentication set `NTCredentials` to the `WebServiceTemplate` sender.

**Axis2 1.7** will have support for NTLMv2 with updated version of the HttpClient 4.2.X, but there is no release date yet.

See:

- `WebServiceTemplate` WS call

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#marshalSendAndReceive%28java.lang.Object%29

- `WebServiceTemplate` sender

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/support/WebServiceAccessor.html#getMessageSenders%28%29

- `NTCredentials`

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/auth/NTCredentials.html

---

**Update**:  I tested Axis 1.7 and the NTLM auth works well.

Answer (score 2):

You are moving from NTLM (1994?) to NTLMv2 (1999) instead of Kerberos based technology (introduced in Windows 2000) because NTLMv2 is more secure???

In terms of interop with Microsoft, modern systems would use WS-Security Kerberos between the JAX-WS client and the .NET service.  This has been tested.

What you are trying to do (replace the Authenticator used by the process) is applicable to a standalone Java application, but does not fit into the Java Enterprise model where the Java process hosts multiple "applications" each with their own "authentication" requirements, never mind the internal requirements imposed by the WebSphere Server processes talking to each other (App Server to App Server, Node Agent to App Server, App Server to LDAP, etc.....)

Comment: I don't choose to go to NTLMv2, the company goes to.

WS-Security is a layer over the transport protocol. NTLMv2 works in the transport layer so I can't go with WS-Security.

Kerberos is a better choice over NTLMv2 but it does not allow load balancing trough DNS because is resistant to Man-In-The-Middle attack. In this case the target IP could change. NTLMv2 is secure, we don't need Kerberos.

I tested some WS stack (Axis2, IBM JAX-WS, Spring WS) with the Authenticator strategy and all them avoid it. But the Authenticator doc says that any net access should look for credentials in it.

Comment: About the Authenticator. I created an small program that sets an Authenticator and calls a WS. If I run this program inside RAD it fails, if you run it from command line it calls the Authenticator to get the credentials and works well. I don't know why.