# NTLM v.2 auth with AXIS2 1.4

Tags: java, apache-axis, ntlm, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using AXIS2 (1.4.2) and related common httpclient 3.1 for creation of webservices. Now I need to create WebService with NTLM v1&2 auth. I found one ticket on AXIS2's jira(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4318) but can't properly understand. Can I use axis2 1.4.2 and http-client 4.0 for NTLM auth

Comment: If you can upgrade to at least Axis 1.7 then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12842649/680925) may help you.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for some work around with 1.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is NO. The New Axis2 1.7 will have a strong dependency of HttpClient 4.0. For using  NTLMv2 authentification you need to create a Authentification Scheme:
http://devsac.blogspot.ru/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html