# Update DNS from Java (Similar to DUC NO - IP).  [Was: Actualizar DNS desde Java (Similar a DUC No-Ip)]

Tags: java, dns, urlconnection

Days ago I try to make an application similar to No-IP DUC (Dynamic DNS Update Clients) in java but I have presented a problem and not how to fix ...
Now I can retrieve the domains I have registered with the following line of code:

```
URLConnection conexion = new URL( "http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/list-hosts.php?email="+USER+"&pass="+PASSWORD ).openConnection();
```

but when I update with the following URL you recommend on page http://www.no-ip.com/integrate/request, I get an exception ...

```
URLConnection conexion = new URL( "http://"+USER+":"+PASSWORD+"@dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname="+DOMAIN+"&myip="+IP ).openConnection();
```

The strange thing is that manually copy the URL in the address, the update is done without problem ...
If anyone can help me I appreciate it a lot ...

Comment: Why did you put the title in Portuguese or Spanish?

Comment: user/pass in the URL string does not work for authentication in `URLConnection`. You need to explicitly enable **Basic Authentication**. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java

Comment: thank you very much for the cooperation ... but I still doubt the link ... that is, I do these steps: http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip47.html but to create the url is giving me an exception MalformedURLException: For input string: "PASSWORD@dynupdate.no-ip.com" and no use linking to create the url and ask me username and password and so do the setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic" + encoding);

Answer (score 1):

Well I faced this situation as well. Found out the reason for this error is that we are using an email address for the username. The "@" present inside it conflicts with the resulting url. Try to use URLEncode to encode the username and the password part.

```
String username = URLEncoder.encode("abc@xyz.com", "UTF-8");
String password = URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL( "http://"+username+":"+password+"@dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname="+hostname+"&myip="+ip);           
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
```

Comment: This might be better as a comment.

Comment: New users are not allowed to comment. I have tried to make it as an answer with relevant code examples.