# URL Class in java

Tags: java

I am using this program in JAVA to get a csv file from the specified URL, but only problem is that it requires username and password that I know, how can I modify this program to include username and password?

```
public class TestGetCSV {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
        URL url12  = new URL("https://wd5-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/customreport2/yahoo3/ISU-YINT061-ProjectsFE/YINT061.05-getWorkersForOpenText?format=csv" );
        URLConnection urlConn = url12.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConn;
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );


        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buff= new BufferedReader(inStream);
        String content2 = buff.readLine();

        while (content2 !=null) {

            System.out.println(content2);
            content2 = buff.readLine();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to remote URL which requires authentication using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is basic authentication based upon HTTP headers you can just open the URL

`https://<username>:<password>@wd5-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/customreport2/yahoo3/ISU-YINT061-ProjectsFE/YINT061.05-getWorkersForOpenText?format=csv`

instead I believe.

However, please keep in mind that this way your credentials are supplied in plaintext.

Comment: Might be worth testing it before you post a potentially incorrect answer.

Comment: As I got no credentials to test it with, it is hard to test. The website seems however to be basic auth with which it should work this way.

Comment: So are there no other testbeds you can use? Like, the website the OP is using?

Comment: @Prior99, I used your code but it shows this error: java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "I6UxYtIp~jLz,#6R"

Comment: @Zawinski Did you just paste your password here? Also, You have to escape the special characters. Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding question for this.

Comment: @stuXnet,no I did not.

Comment: @Prior99 no i used this: String userpass = "username" + ":" + "password"; String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes()); uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);