# Android making server request

Tags: java, php, android

I'm currently making an app under Android which enable me to connect a user. I use regular android server request. I call a php file stored on my server which look if the user entered is currently registered in the BDD, but it's not working at all...

This is my php file :

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "userpass", "Android");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"]

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Utilisateur where username = ? AND password = ?");


mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password); 
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $username, $mail, $password, $adresse, $ville, $zipCode);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
  $user[name] = $name;
  $user[username] = $username;
  $user[mail] = $mail;
  $user[password] = $password;
  $user[adresse] = $adresse;
  $user[ville] = $ville;
  $user[zipCode] = $zipCode;
}

echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

This is my request fonction in Java (there is a user:password because you need to authenticate in order to acces any web page on my server)

```
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://user:userpassword@62.210.193.223/Android/";

public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallBack userCallBack;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallBack callBack) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallBack = callBack;
        }


        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            User returnedUser;

            try {

                URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("username", user.username)
                        .appendQueryParameter("password", user.password);

                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

                String response = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
                JSONObject jResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                if (jResponse.length() == 0) {
                    returnedUser = null;
                } else {
                    String name = jResponse.getString("name");
                    String mail = jResponse.getString("mail");
                    String adresse = jResponse.getString("adresse");
                    String ville = jResponse.getString("ville");
                    int zipCode = jResponse.getInt("zipCode");

                    returnedUser = new User(name, user.name, user.password, mail, adresse, ville, zipCode);


                }
                return returnedUser;


            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallBack.done(returnedUser);
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        }

    }
```

I launched my application in debug mode and I catched this exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://user:userpassword@62.210.193.223/Android/FetchUserData.php
```

I even tried to C/C the url in my web browser and it execute the file. Of course it returned [] because I did not include POST in my call.

I'm completly lost because android is quite new to me and I dont really know where to look to find a solution to this problem... If someone could help me to solve this problem it would be very much appreciated :)

Cheers,
Astrus

Comment: i think `"http://user:userpassword@62.210.193.223/Android/"` is not a valid server address.. try to use `"http://62.210.193.223/Android/"`

Comment: My suggestion is to check if url is online or not before going to call in android..try with any browse if its working proper.

Comment: I tried and I obtained the exact same problem :/

Comment: check if it works on browser..if not then thats the problem, link is not online

Comment: Like I said in my request, I have tried in my regular web Browser ELITE and its working fine...

Comment: add `conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);` after `conn.setRequestMethod("POST");` and remove line `conn.connect();`

Comment: I have changed the input as you said and I ran in debug mode. I catched the same exact exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://62.210.193.223/Android/FetchUserData.php By the way, thank you for trying to help me it's much appreciated :)

Comment: I need to execute the php file on the server and get the output of the request. You're suggestion it's for downloading a file from a server I think it will not help no ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using BasicAuth for HTTP security. Providing username and password is not the good way to provide *Basic* credentials for your request.

You need to set the correct *Authorization* header :

```
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
String userpass = username + ":" + password;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

See : [Connecting to remote URL which requires authentication using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm pretty new to Android so it's not completly clear to me yet. Should I add this code next to my :

URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

Or should I replace the code ?

Astrus

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the good answer, please validate it to close your question.

Comment: You just need to remove user name and password from SERVER_ADDRESS and put it in your code just after conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); I have not tried but other parts must be OK