# Send Https request through Java but getting unauthorized error-401

Tags: java, web-services

I am sending Https request with username and password through 2 ways but in both the cases I am getting Error 401- Unauthorized error

1. direct connection through URLConnection

   ```
   try {
       URL url = new URL("https://xxx.xxxxx.com/v1/limit/5");
       URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
       HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
       if(urlConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
           String authStr = "username"+":"+"password";
           byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(authStr.getBytes());
           String authEncoded = new String(bytesEncoded);
           connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+authEncoded);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter an HTTPs URL.");
            return;
        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String urlString = "";
        String current;
        while((current = in.readLine()) != null) {
            urlString += current;
        }
        System.out.println(urlString);
   } catch(IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Connection through Jersey Client but in the same way I am getting 401-unauth error

Comment: Since it's not working in any of those cases: Is it possible, that you in fact are unauthorized or not using the correct authentication mechanism?

Comment: I check the same credential for Postman rest client and the API worked fine. I am not sure if I missed something

Comment: If you're using Postman you could use its "Generate Code" feature. It should be easy to find any missing headers (Accept, Content-Type) or differences in the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to remote URL which requires authentication using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java)