# How to use login:pass@ url in Glide on Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-glide

Trying Glide library for Android. It is necessary to download pictures and display it in the ImageView.
If this type url

```
http: //www.some.domen / storage / images / image.jpg
```

all normal loaded.
But if you are denied access login and password so

`http: // USER: PASSWORD@www.some.domen/storage/images` ...

the picture is not loaded.
What's wrong, how do I upload a picture using the username and password?
Thank you!

Comment: Crosslink: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1579

Answer (score 4):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137446/253468 I think this could be a workaround/solution (untested):

```
LazyHeaders auth = new LazyHeaders.Builder() // can be cached in a field and reused
        .addHeader("Authorization", new BasicAuthorization(username, password))
        .build();

Glide
        .with(context)
        .load(new GlideUrl(url, auth)) // GlideUrl is created anyway so there's no extra objects allocated
        .into(imageView);

public class BasicAuthorization implements LazyHeaderFactory {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public BasicAuthorization(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override public String buildHeader() {
        return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
}
```