# How to authenticate with Glide/GlideSlider

Tags: android, slider, android-glide

I want to load some images that come from google drive using Glide with GlideSlider

But everytime I try to download an image through url an IO error comes up because I don't have permission..

What I'm doing:

```
requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.centerCrop();

    for (int i = 0; i < url_fotos.size(); i++) {
        TextSliderView sliderView = new TextSliderView(activity);
        // if you want show image only / without description text use DefaultSliderView instead

        // initialize SliderLayout
        sliderView
                .image(url_fotos.get(i))
                .setRequestOption(requestOptions)
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                .setProgressBarVisible(true)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView baseSliderView) {

                    }
                });

        //add your extra information
        sliderLayout.addSlider(sliderView);
    }

    sliderLayout.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Default);
```

I've already tried:
"http://username:password@domain.com/url"

And tried this too:

[How to use login:pass@ url in Glide on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538176/how-to-use-loginpass-url-in-glide-on-android/)

what else can i do to login in my account?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is related to Authentication then as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855448/3746306) :

You should obtain `fileId` from `Google Drive SDK API` and then use this url :

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileId}