# Quick way to programmatically deploy artifacts to Nexus (in Java)

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface, nexus

I currently write a Java program that deploys a lot of legacy jars to Nexus. My approach is to invoke a process that starts the `deploy:deploy-file` goal on the command line

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file ...
```

This is quite slow. I wonder if there is a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you specifically target Nexus, you might find simpler to use [their REST API](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus) to perform the upload:

> Here are some examples using curl.
>
> 1. Uploading an artifact and generating a pom file:
>
>    ```
>    curl -v -F r=releases -F hasPom=false -F e=jar -F g=com.test -F a=project -F v=1.0 -F p=jar -F file=@project-1.0.jar -u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content
>    ```
> 2. Uploading an artifact with a pom file:
>
>    ```
>    curl -v -F r=releases -F hasPom=true -F e=jar -F file=@pom.xml -F file=@project-1.0.jar -u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content
>    ```

In a Java program, you can then use `HttpURLConnection` to make that POST call ([example of that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657510/1743880) with [authentication here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137446/1743880) and [documentation of cURL here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)). Basically, in the POST parameters, you need to have `r=releases`, `hasPom=true` (or `false` if you're uploading a POM with it), `e` for the extension of the artifact, `g`, `a`, `v` and `p` for the coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version and packaging) and finally `file` for the file to deploy.

Note that you won't be able to upload snapshots [because it is explicitely disabled](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus#comment_203642958).

---

If you want a more generic solution, that would work for whatever artifact, and for whatever remote repository (even a local one), you can directly use the Aether API, which is used under the scenes by Maven 3.1 and higher. The team has an example of such a task in the [`DeployArtifacts`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/tree/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/DeployArtifacts.java) sample.

Add to your project the Aether dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${aetherVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-connector-basic</artifactId>
        <version>${aetherVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${aetherVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${aetherVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <aetherVersion>1.1.0</aetherVersion>
    <mavenVersion>3.3.9</mavenVersion>
</properties>
```

And then you can have the following code to deploy artifacts:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DeploymentException {
    RepositorySystem system = newRepositorySystem();
    RepositorySystemSession session = newSession(system);

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact("groupId", "artifactId", "classifier", "extension", "version");
    artifact = artifact.setFile(new File("/path/to/file"));

    // add authentication to connect to remove repository
    Authentication authentication = new AuthenticationBuilder().addUsername("username").addPassword("password").build();

    // creates a remote repo at the given URL to deploy to
    RemoteRepository distRepo = new RemoteRepository.Builder("id", "default", "url").setAuthentication(authentication).build();

    DeployRequest deployRequest = new DeployRequest();
    deployRequest.addArtifact(artifact);
    deployRequest.setRepository(distRepo);

    system.deploy(session, deployRequest);
}

private static RepositorySystem newRepositorySystem() {
    DefaultServiceLocator locator = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator();
    locator.addService(RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.class);
    locator.addService(TransporterFactory.class, FileTransporterFactory.class);
    locator.addService(TransporterFactory.class, HttpTransporterFactory.class);
    return locator.getService(RepositorySystem.class);
}

private static RepositorySystemSession newSession(RepositorySystem system) {
    DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();
    LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository("target/local-repo");
    session.setLocalRepositoryManager(system.newLocalRepositoryManager(session, localRepo));
    return session;
}
```

This code will deploy a single artifact having the given coordinates (groupId, artifactId, type, classifier and version) to the configured remote repository:

- In the coordinates, you can pass an empty String to leave it blank. For example, to deploy without a classifier, you can use `""` as the classifier.
- The file to deploy is set with the method `setFile` on the `Artifact`.
- The remote repository is configured with its ID, layout and URL. The `"default"` layout is the one used by Maven 2 repository (in contrast to the [`"legacy"`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-in-legacy-layout.html) layout for Maven 1). The URL is the same one as you would use inside the [`deploy-file` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#url), so `file:///C:/m2-repo` or `scp://host.com/path/to/repo`.
- If necessary, you can create an `Authentication` to connect to the remote repository (as shown in the snippet).

If you wish to deploy attached artifacts with it, like a POM file, you can create a `SubArtifact` with:

```
Artifact pomArtifact = new SubArtifact(artifact, "", "pom");
pomArtifact = pomArtifact.setFile(new File("pom.xml"));
```

This would attach a POM artifact, without classifier, to the artifact configured above. Then you can add it to the deploy request like the main one:

```
deployRequest.addArtifact(artifact).addArtifact(pomArtifact);
```

and the both of them will be deployed.

Comment: The link to the DeployArtifacts sample doesn't work anymore. Any ideas where that might be now?

Comment: Oh just needed to google it: https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/blob/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/DeployArtifacts.java

Answer (score 3):

You can do it programmatically in Java with the Eclipse Aether API. Check out the source of my [Maven Repository Tools](https://github.com/simpligility/maven-repository-tools/tree/master/maven-repository-provisioner) for  more detail. In fact you might be able to use it straight out of the box for your needs if all your artifacts are already in a local folder in Maven repository format.

Specifically the deployment related code is in

https://github.com/simpligility/maven-repository-tools/blob/master/maven-repository-provisioner/src/main/java/com/simpligility/maven/provisioner/MavenRepositoryDeployer.java