# How do you execute cURL statements in java to fetch JSON from kibana

Tags: java, json, maven, curl, kibana

I'm creating a small web application to make the lives of some ElasticSearch admins easier in ES 5.x. I'm familiar with Java but have never used cURL before.

The setup is a Thymeleaf website using Java and Maven.

In 5.x the roles can only be fetched from the console in kibana, which is executed with the curl statement `curl -XGET "(url)/_xpack/security/role`, but with some username params.

I've done some research but I'm not sure if any of these solutions fit my criteria. The closest answer I found was https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587534/7137657 but the binding is in version 0.2 and with no real documentation or explanation.

The other solutions suggest using java.net.URL and java.net.URLConnection classes, but I don't see how to use those with a password and username, let alone use the kibana console once connected and return the JSON.

This is only be beginning of the process. They already have access to kibana. I want to use the JSON to let them edit the security groups in YAML after (will also be done in the web application).

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at answer to this question on how to use authentication with URL/URLConnection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/496707/780998

Complete example [HERE](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1081/)

Comment: that looks good for authentication! I'm still unsure how to execute the console command and return the JSON through.

Comment: cURL is ALSO a library that you can use from Java, aside from a command-line tool. The response above is NOT about cURL though, it is about using URL/URLConnection as detailed in the answer you linked in your original question. If you combine the answer I linked with the answer in your question, you should have a viable solution. If you're looking for a cut-n-paste answer, try this: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-to-a-url-using-basic-authentication.html