# groovy - Download file with authentication

Tags: http, authentication, groovy, httprequest, basic-authentication

I need to download a text file using basic authentication (the kind of authentication that prompts the browser to ask you for domain\username and password) using Groovy. I would like to avoid using additional libraries, isn't there anything to do this in in Groovy?

My current code is:

```
new File("test.txt").withOutputStream { out ->
    def url = new URL(myurl).openConnection()

    def remoteAuth = "Basic " + "myusername:mypassword".bytes.encodeBase64()
    url.setRequestProperty("Authorization", remoteAuth);
    out << url.inputStream
}
```

But the server replies with a 401 error. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Groovy uses the `java.net.Authenticator` API. You can provide a default `Authenticator` using  [`java.net.Authenticator#setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html#setDefault(java.net.Authenticator)). An Example for an BasicAuth usage can be found [in another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496707/212749).

```
Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked immediately! I deleted the two Auth lines from my code and added yours.