# Eclipse Kura http authentication failed

Tags: java, eclipse, http, get, kura

I am trying to do a simple HTTP Get and POST request in java to my Eclipse Kura gateway but i dont know how to authenticate using username and password. I tried using the url syntax http://user:pw@ipaddress:port/ but i still get HTTP error code 401.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HTTP {

public static String getHTML() throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    String urlToRead = "http://user:pw@ipaddress:port";

    URL url = new URL(urlToRead);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getHTML());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are not providing the credentials in the desired way. [This very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java) already has an accepted answer, in which James Van Huis suggests using `java.net.Authenticator` for setting authentication data prior to opening any connections.