# Connect to remote URL with domain, username and pw

Tags: java, http, authentication, base64, authorization

Heys guys, following problem here:
I have a username which looks like "ABCD\michael" and a password which looks like "password!6789". "ABCD" in this case is the domain.

With the following code, im getting 401 unauthorized as a response code.
I suspect, that the doublebackslashes are not being converted to a single backslash prior the base64 encoding. Or am I using the domain in a wrong way?

I need help to get this working. Help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

```
public int getMeTheResponseCodeOfURL(final URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;
    int statusCode = 0;
    String userName = "ABCD\\michael";
    String userPass = "password!6789";
    String UserAndPass = userName + ":" + userPass;
    String userPassBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(UserAndPass.getBytes());

    try {
        httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + userPassBase64);
        httpUrlConnection.connect();
        statusCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();

    } catch (final IOException e) {
        this.log.error("IO Exception! Errormessage: " + e);
    }
    return statusCode;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried only the username (without domain) or `user@domain`?

Comment: @Quetsalkoatl I tried both ways. Sadly still 401.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try and replace the \ sign with %5C
This is the encode code for the slash. 
So your username will look like this:

```
String userName = "ABCD%5Cmichael"
```

Comment: check this link I think it contains your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java/496707

Comment: Before I asked this question, I tried every way this link contains. Still, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is using `UserAndPass.getBytes("UTF-8")`, though your UserAndPass string only contains US-ASCII characters - so it may not matter - but remember that `String.getBytes()` [1] (with no args) encodes the string bytes using the default platform charset, which may not always be what you want. It is rarely a good idea to depend on the default charset.

Also if "ABCD" is the authentication realm then it might no need to be part of the UserAndPass string - see RFC 7617 [2]

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()

[2] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617