# CSV from URL with basic authentication and Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I need to parse a CSV input from an `URL`. That's not so complicated but the `URL` needs a basic authentication. Is there a way to use basic authentication for the CSV input directly with Jackson or do I need to read the input in as a String and parse it afterwards with Jackson?

```
private static List<Result> read(URL url) throws IOException {
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Result.class).withColumnReordering(true).withColumnSeparator(',').withHeader();
    ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(Result.class).with(schema);

    return reader.<Result>readValues(url).readAll(); // how to use basic authentication here?
}
```

Comment: you could try to add the username and password in the URL (like eg. http://username:password@URL).

Comment: you can use a general Authenticator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/496707/1514647